# Autolaoder - filenotification with modifiedBefore

Tags: pyspark, streaming, azure-databricks, databricks-autoloader

With the current configuration, evey 1h we get new folder with new data in it.

[See image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HzQl.png)

I'm leveraging file notification, and I prefer not to switch to directory listing. However, I encounter an issue with constantly updated CSV files in the latest folder. This causes job failures when the Autoloader attempts to read a CSV file being updated at that moment. I'm exploring ways to exclude the latest folder from being read and have come across the modifiedBefore parameter, but I'm uncertain about its compatibility with the FileNotification.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: its not clear how it will work with fileNotification. if I use `modifiedBefore` will it still create the blob queues? while I was testing was not clear for me.

Comment: when you use file notification mode, Auto Loader automatically sets up a notification service and queue service that subscribes to file events from the input directory. `modifiedBefore` is just generic option it doen't creates any queues.

Answer (score 0):

**`modifiedBefore`** is a generic option in autoloader, which can be used with file notification mode.

You mentioned that files arrive every hour and the latest file is updated very frequently, causing errors when you do incremental load using autoloader.

To avoid this, you can either provide a path with a pattern that matches all files except the latest one or use the **`modifiedBefore`** option.

In both cases, you should know the timestamp.

For example, if you don't need the data after `13:00:00`, you can use patterns like below:

```py
"/2023-12-20T(0[0-9]|1[0-2]).[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9]Z/"
```

For more information about patterns you can refer this [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/en/ingestion/auto-loader/patterns.html).

Or, you can use the **`modifiedBefore`** option:

```py
autoloader_config = {
"cloudFiles.format":"csv",
"cloudFiles.useNotifications": "true",
"cloudFiles.resourceGroup":resourcegroup,
"cloudFiles.clientId": client_id,
"cloudFiles.clientSecret": client_secret,
"cloudFiles.tenantId": tenant_id,
"cloudFiles.connectionString":conn_string,
"cloudFiles.subscriptionId": subscription_id,
"cloudFiles.schemaLocation":schema_location,
"header": True,
"modifiedBefore":"2023-12-20 13:00:00.000000 UTC+5:30"
}
```

If you want to filter based on the last hour, you can use the following code to get that:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

india_dt = datetime.now(tz=ZoneInfo("Asia/Kolkata"))
filter  = india_dt -  timedelta(hours=1)
```

This gives: `2023-12-20 11:41:39.862054+05:30`

You can then use that filter in the **`modifiedBefore`** option.

**Note**: You need to specify the zone that matches the folder names created every hour.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing large files at some location, and there is a possibility that the job that reads these files might run some files might be incomplete, then you'll have to write some code / do some juggling in the job that reads the files.

Usually this problem is solved by changing the understanding with the job that writes the files, change it's logic so writing a new file is a two step process:

1. Write file with to a separate folder `in-progress/<final-file-name>`
2. Rename/move file from `in-progress/<final-file-name>` to `staging/<final-file-name>`.

In most cloud file systems renaming is an atomic operation so your reader will never be able to to read an incomplete file.

If your reader is looking for specific file suffixes/patterns then you can also use `<final-file-name>.in-progress` instead of a separate folder. Logic remains the same.